# Remapping Android hardware keys on CyanogenMod

Tags: root-access, multitasking

What I'm really disappointed about Android is its multitasking. The recent apps list quickly gets cluttered with apps I won't use in any near future. I'd like to be able to quickly kill an app I know I won't need anymore today.

Examples:

- home button kills the current activity (if any)
- home button kills the current activity (if any) and triggers the recents. The recents works as usual - doesn't kill any app
- double tapping the home button kills the current activity and triggers the recent, single tapping works as usual

How can I achieve it? I know about GravityBox but it's not supposed to be installed on non-AOSP phones (I'm running CyanogenMod in this case).

I have root access available.

Comment: Gravity Box worked pretty well for me on TouchWiz ( Samsung) also non aosp as well as heavily modded emui interface of Huawei- not all but lot of features did work. Doesn't harm to try

Comment: How about "Back-button kills the current activity (if any)"? It does when long-pressing it – provided you've activated that feature in developer settings (at the very end of the screen). A feature I use on different CM devices for years, and won't miss anymore :) // GravityBox does not work on *all* flavors of CM, unfortunately, but on several at least (if the ROM is based on bandwagon, it should work).

Comment: Yes, but the long-press is about 3 seconds - much too long. Short pressing is an instant.

Comment: "non AOSP phones"CyanogenMod and pretty much all custom Roms are based on AOSP.

Comment: @xangua: *SHOULD NOT be used with custom ROMs like CM, AOSPA, RootBox, SlimBean and others - it makes no sense since the most of the features are already in the ROM (may cause conflicts and unexpected behaviour)*